# Telegram api: запретить сворачивать кнопки

Tags: php, telegram

У юзеров после манипуляций с ботов автоматически сворачиваются кнопки под окном ввода, юзеры не догадываются кликнуть иконку разворота кнопок. Можно ли их запретить сворачивать?

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup `one_time_keyboard=False`

Comment: Нельзя, это функционал приложения-клиента. Вы можете взаимодействовать только с API